# Re-ask email permission from facebook, if user has first declined it on external login (Asp.net 5 using OWIN)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, owin, facebook-login

Email is mandatory field in my .net application using web-api 2.0 and OWIN for facebook login. How can I ask permission for email again, if user first denied email on Facebook external login but allowed other permissions and successfully logged in.

I am in **GetExternalLogin** method of web-api2 template, which calls external login consent screen. I am getting other **ExternalLoginData** as other permissions allowed by user, but not email. The consent screen has set the External Cookie.

Now application showing user is authenticated and not challenging again for email. How can I call the consent screen to re-ask email permission.

Comment: Why i did not receive any answer, not even a single comment as help on this question? Is the question not clear or their is no answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After no response for multiple days, I myself got answer on facebook. We can do this by adding the auth_type=rerequest parameter to Login Dialog URL.

Link 1: [Re-asking for Declined Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/#reaskperms)

Link 2: [Re-asking for Declined Permissions using ASP.Net Identity OWIN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41975557/1129978)